Wikipedia short descriptions via API
Wikipedia has in the past few years added short descriptions to most pages, which are useful super-short snippets giving an overview of the topic of a page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Short_description#Short_descriptions_on_redirect_pages
Is there any way to retrieve them via the official API? The most recent version of the Search API doesn't indicate a related property (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search), and I was wondering if someone had been trying to retrieve the same property.

It's available via the action=query&prop=description API.

Interesting, this works perfectly although the 'description' property is flagged as "internal" in the query documentation
